# Karate UI testing open one browser instance for all test cases

Tags: karate, browser-automation

I have multiple test cases for each test case it is opening new browser, how to open just one browser instance and navigate all to all Url.
In parallel execution it opens multiple browsers don't need parallel. Ecexute on test cases one by one on one chrome browser instance